# How would one go about capturing a Tarrasque for 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

My team and I want to create a Tarrasque Bomb.

What is a Tarrasque Bomb?

1. Capture a Tarrasque through some means (Somehow putting it into a bag of holding is one of our main ideas).
2. Transport what which contains the Tarrasque to an unsuspecting city.
3. The Tarrasque explodes out from whatever holds it.
4. Utter Chaos Ensues, with Me and my Team perfectly safe from harm.

How do we do this by using the available spells, items, and abilities for this edition of D&D?

Comment: Might this question be eligible for reopening?  Cheese in a variety of flavors, and clever manipulation of spells and items, is the bread and butter of some brands of D&D fun.  I think that making this more of "our group wants to do this, how do we do it?" kind of question may get it re opened. I made an edit.  Hopefully that suffices.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I don't think this can be edited into suitability. It's idea generation, which is immediately at risk of being too broad. It's also on the border between "good" and "bad" subjective, given how much DM fiat & rules lawyering the Big T seems to engender. If the asker had a specific plan we could give feedback on it, but comparing different ideas is inherently difficult due to varying party composition, magic item availability, house rules, setting, scenario, and countless other factors.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### How to capture the Tarrasque for transportation and later use

Firstly, some base constraints. The Tarrasque (henceforth referred to as "Big T") can't be affected by any spell that requires a ranged attack roll or has a line area of effect. Also, I'm assuming that a giant Tarrasque statue isn't portable enough for your purposes. Finally, anything that involves a saving throw will have to be usable at least 4 times, since Big T can choose to succeed the first 3 saving throws with Legendary Resistance.

So, in order from simplest to most complicated:

1. The *Imprisonment* spell. The Minimus Containment option will do nicely for your purposes. The only downside is that it's a 9th-level spell which takes a minute to cast, and, as mentioned, you'll have to hit Big T with it at least 4 times. Even then, it's really good at making saving throws.
2. The *True Polymorph* spell. Pretty much the same as *Imprisonment*, you turn Big T into a portable object or a small creature that you can carry around. If you want to unleash it more than an hour after capture, you'll need to use *Dispel Magic*.
3. The *Polymorph* spell. This one only works for up to an hour, but as a 4th-level spell it's a lot easier to keep using it until Big T fails a saving throw. Plus if your DM is nice, you can use *Conjure Woodland Beings* to get 8 pixies, then have them cast *Polymorph* for you - 8 spells for the price of one!
4. A Mirror of Life Trapping. You need to have one, and you need to trick Big T into looking at it, and Big T needs to fail his saving throw. But other than that, it works perfectly for you.
5. An Iron Flask. This one only works if Big T is on a plane that isn't the Material Plane, and he still needs to fail a saving throw. And, you need to have one. But other than that, it works *really* well - it even forces him to obey your commands when you unleash him! If this is enough of a draw for you, consider using *Plane Shift* to get Big T off the Material Plane. It's better than it sounds, because he'll probably use up all his Legendary Resistances foiling your *Plane Shift*, so he'll be relatively vulnerable for the Iron Flask.
6. The *Wish* spell. *Wish* can, theoretically, do anything. It all depends on how good you are at wording the wish and how generous (or not) your DM is at interpreting it. I put this one last because it's by far the most risky - being killed by Big T could be the least of your worries compared to a wish that goes horribly wrong.

Comment: You don't need 4 "copies" of the same spell, you need to make it use its Legendary Resistance 3 times, snd there are other ways to make it happen. On the other hand, you may need more because of its high saves.

Comment: @Chepelink Remember, your DM gets to choose what the Tarrasque does or doesn't use Legendary Resistance on - if they know you're aiming to bottle Godzilla, there's nothing stopping them from saving their freebies. Even if they're not trying to block this specifically, everything here (except polymorph) is basically save-or-permanent-imprisonment, and that, along with save-or-die, is the whole reason Legendary Resistance even exists.

Comment: Also... on the whole using Conjure Woodland Beings thing... any conjure spell really... to CHOOSE what shows up; you will want to reference the Sage Advice answers page to see that the player casts the spell but only the GM decides what shows up as intended and how they behave under the GMs control. The only 'choice' a player gets is making a hopeful request as to what is summoned and more requests as to what they do once summoned.

Comment: @Airatome Yeah, I'm so used to ignoring that (pretty crappy) ruling that I forgot about it. I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Miniman Yup, I know, but there are tons of save or suck abilities that can cripple the tarrasque. And, unless the DM knows what to expect, the tarrasque doesn't know so... Why would it save its ability? Also, for sake of strategy, you don't want to use precious resources on something that is gonna fail, better use alternatives. I think that the last part is what makes this kind of plans interesting (how to make it uses its egendary Resistance)

Comment: @Miniman It IS pretty crappy...as a druid that loves having extra minions around I agree. For the sake of RAW accuracy though....had to point it out.

Comment: Even if the pixies don't fly [/rimshot], a bunch of *Polymorph* spells would be a nice way to grind down the 3 uses of Legendary Resistance.

Comment: @Miniman I found a way to cheese the encounter,it require the help of intellect devourers (e. g.  true polymorph). Since big t has a int score of 3 is guaranteed that if it fails the int savings throw, it'll be stunned. As long as it cannot regain a point in int it'll be perma stunned. Also, is perfect for burning its Legendary Resistance.

Comment: And if allowed (might be possible, might not), polymorph into a low int humanoid, devour it, posses him, dispell the polymorph and now you are a big t... If it is allowed...

Comment: Now after capturing it, breed it with a bronze dragon for that yellow color and lightning breath.... .... ..... specially if the iron flask is red, white and round.